# Create a html list from an rss file using xslt

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, rss

XSLT newbie question.
I want to create a html list from an rss file using xslt. 
I was able to do so with an rss file and a xslt file.

But now I tried create the html list the output is empty.

This is my current code:

```
string xmlsrc = "http://.../News.rss";
string Password = "myPass";
string UserAccount = "myAcc";
string DomainName = "myDom";
string xslsrc = "RSS91.xslt";

if (xmlsrc != "")
{
    HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(xmlsrc);

    if (UserAccount != "")
    {
        wr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserAccount, Password, DomainName);
    }

    wr.Timeout = 10000;
    WebResponse resp = wr.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();

    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
    reader.XmlResolver = null;

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(reader);

    xmlRSS.Document = doc;
}
xmlRSS.TransformSource = xslsrc;
```

My XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="iso-8859-1" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="menus">
      <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="menu">
          <li>
            <a href="{title}">
              <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </a>
            <ul>
              <xsl:for-each select="submenu">
                <li>
                  <a href="{title}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                  </a>
                </li>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XSLT you have doesn't seem to have a template for processing RSS files.

If you have an RSS file with the structure:

```
/rss
   /channel
      /item
         /title
         /link
   /channel
      /item
         /title
         /link
```

You can generate a list to print the links to the feeds replacing in your XSLT `menus` with `rss`, `menu` with `channel` and `submenu` with `item`. Also, your `href` is pointing to the text not the link, so replace the `href="{title}"` with `href="{link}"`. This template might work:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="rss">
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="channel">
                <li>
                    <a href="{link}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:for-each select="item">
                            <li>
                                <a href="{link}">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

You still might have problems. There may be namespaces such as `atom` or `feedburner`, or your root element might be `channel` and not `rss`. For the namespaces, you should add them to the header:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:atom10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0"> ...
```

To avoid problems with different root elements, make your template match `channel` and use `/` to build the structure of your HTML. Here's a full stylesheet. If you have many channels in a `<rss>` rooted file, it will print a list of them, with sublists containing the items. If you have a `<channel>` root, it will also work, printing the only list item, and its rss items in a sublist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:atom10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="iso-8859-1" />

    <xsl:template match="channel">
        <li>
            <a href="{link}">
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </a>
            <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select="item">
                    <li>
                        <a href="{link}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>RSS feeds</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//channel"/>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @user3436943 Please accept this answer (mark the tick on the left so that it appears in green) if it solved your problem.